# Is it better to have one listener or four listeners for fetching data?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

This is a performance question regarding firebase. I hope an expert would help me and I will try to make it as simple as possible.

I am building a Web HTML5 cards game (Very similar to Spades) where there are four players on the table and each player has to bid (between 7 and 13), I am going to call them:

- player1
- player2
- player3
- player4

So, they look like that on Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

Supposedly now, **player3** has bid from his side. The bid should be displayed on:

- player1
- player2
- player4

Now, what I do is that for each player, I create three listeners for the remaining players, so if we are on **player4**'s side. The code is similar to this (in my code is done via for loop, but here changed for simplicity):

```
var player1Ref = firebase.database().ref('/table/1/bid/player1');
player1Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) window.alert("Player 1 has bid!"); 
});

var player2Ref = firebase.database().ref('/table/1/bid/player2');
player2Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) window.alert("Player 2 has bid!"); 
});

var player3Ref = firebase.database().ref('/table/1/bid/player3');
player3Ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) window.alert("Player 3 has bid!"); 
});
```

Now, this works really fine for me. But I wonder if this is the best way to do it. The alternative would be creating a reference spy on "**bid**" but it might be worse because it fetches all the data whereas individual references get less data but they have more listeners.

Which way is the best way?

Comment: The question is a little vague and doesn't really explain why there are multiple listeners. Can you attach a single observer to the *bid* node? That will notify the app when any of the players bid. Even attaching it to the *1* node (assuming that's the game number)?